# Ruby on Rails Difficult Form/Associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails 4.2 app which has 'Rooms', 'Bookings' and 'Extras'.

When making a booking it is for a room e.g. website.com/rooms/1/bookings/1

I have extras which I want to be associated with the booking for that room via check-boxes.

How can this be implemented? I've been reading about `has_many :foo, :through => :bar` associations but I'm not sure if that's the way to go.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
<!-- app\views\bookings\_form.html.erb -->

<%= form_for([@room, @booking]) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Select Customer:' %>
    <%= f.collection_select :user_id, User.all, :id, :customer_name %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'start_time', 'Start Date and Time:' %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :start_time, { minute_step: 15 } %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'length', 'Length of booking in hours:' %>
    <%= f.number_field 'length', min: 1 %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Room Price:' %>
    <%= number_to_currency @room.price, unit: "£" %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label 'Extras:' %>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :extra_ids, Extra.all, :id, :extra_info %>
  </p>
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
<% end %>

# app\models\booking.rb
class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :additions
  has_many :extras, :through => :additions
end

# app\models\extra.rb
class Extra < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :extracat
  has_many :additions
  has_many :bookings, :through => :additions

  def extra_info
    "#{name}"
  end
end

# This model is for the has_many through testing I tried
# app\models\addition.rb
class Addition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :booking
  belongs_to :extra
end

# Relevant section of schema
create_table "additions", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "booking_id"
  t.integer  "extra_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end

create_table "bookings", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "start_time"
  t.datetime "end_time"
  t.integer  "length"
  t.integer  "room_id"
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "extra_id"
end
```

EDIT - The section within the bookings show page.

```
# app\views\bookings\show.html.erb
<% @booking.extras.each do |e| %>
  <%= e.name %>,
<% end %>
```

EDIT - Adding bookings controller

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :xml, :json

  before_action :find_room

  def index
    @bookings = Booking.where("room_id = ? AND end_time >= ?", @room.id, Time.now).order(:start_time)
    respond_with @bookings
  end

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new(room_id: @room.id)
  end

  def create
    @booking =  Booking.new(params[:booking].permit(:room_id, :start_time, :length))
    @booking.room = @room
    if @booking.save
      redirect_to room_bookings_path(@room, method: :get)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id]).destroy
    if @booking.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Booking: #{@booking.start_time.strftime('%e %b %Y %H:%M%p')} to #{@booking.end_time.strftime('%e %b %Y %H:%M%p')} deleted"
      redirect_to room_bookings_path(@room)
    else
      render 'index'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
    # @booking.room = @room

    if @booking.update(params[:booking].permit(:room_id, :start_time, :length))
      flash[:notice] = 'Your booking was updated succesfully'

      if request.xhr?
        render json: {status: :success}.to_json
      else
        redirect_to resource_bookings_path(@room)
      end
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  private

  def save booking
    if @booking.save
        flash[:notice] = 'booking added'
        redirect_to room_booking_path(@room, @booking)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
  end

  def find_room
    if params[:room_id]
      @room = Room.find_by_id(params[:room_id])
    end
  end

  def booking_params
     params.require(:booking).permit(:user_id, :extra_id)
  end

end
```

How is it possible to associate the extras with a booking? As so far they are not being saved with the booking into the database. Is this a controller issue?

Comment: If you uncomment the extras & additions associations then it looks good to me

Comment: @FrederickCheung It does look fine, I've been reading a couple of tutorials, but it doesn't save the `extra_id` to the bookings table.

Comment: It shouldn't - that field isn't needed for those associations.

Comment: @FrederickCheung Oh right. How is it possible to get the selected extras to display on the 'show' page? I've added the code section. Is that not correct?

Comment: @Koxzi.  It shouldn't save to the bookings table as it is not a 1-1 relationship (in fact you don't need the 'extra_id' field there at all), rather it should save to your joins table.  Are the booking-extra pairings saving to your additions table?  If not, are the parameters from the checkbox passing through to your create action in your bookings controller?

Comment: @FunTimeFreddie Ok that makes sense. No they aren't saving to the additions table at all which led me to think it was a controller issue. I wasn't aware that I would have to change the controller for the checkboxes.

Comment: You could add this or something similar to the controller, in the create action once the booking is saved.  I've used this before but not from this type of form (for two variables, booking and room), so I'm not exactly sure of the format of the parameters, but you may be able to tailor....

params[:booking][:extra_ids].each { |p|; @booking.extras << Extra.find(p.to_i)}

Comment: The controller could be at fault if you are not permitting the parameters properly.

Comment: @FrederickCheung I don't actually have an additions controller. Could this be why? Admittedly I was following a tutorial from a few years ago. They just generated the model individually and the table.

Comment: You don't need one - it's only the bookings controller that is involved

Comment: @FrederickCheung I suspected as much, the parameters seem fine in the usual `permit` section. Added the controller.

Comment: @FrederickCheung Ok I've tried your solution. I did add a comment but I cannot mention for whatever reason. Still the additions table is not showing any data. Is there nothing I need to add into the controller create action at all? As nothing is displaying on the show page either (which is obvious).

Comment: Ah I hadn't spotted that you don't actually use your booking_params method in the create action - you need to change the permit call in that method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not permitting the parameters correctly - the name is `extra_ids`. In addition since the parameter is an array you need to permit it like so:

```
params.require(:booking).permit(:room_id, :start_time, :length, :extra_ids => [])
```

Personally I recommend setting action controller to raise an error when unpermitted parameters are encountered in development or tests - very easy otherwise to miss the log messages